# SEO Single page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine

I have a single page Wordpress site, it takes all content on the homepage from other posts. I have yoast plugin installed but i'm wondering do I enter the keywords on each of these posts and place a 301 redirect so that when it appears it goes only to the homepage or do I non-index these posts and place the keywords on the page that is taking in these posts?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Google indexes pages based on their URLs. If you build a "one page" website, you have only one page/URL. What will be displayed on post's URLs  ? If there are pages on it, optimise them and index them but you are no longer on a "one page" website. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the meta description in Yoast or AIO SEO, it will display it instead of your latest posts information in the Google search results.

Use this tool to assist you in creating a perfect looking SERP result: http://dejanseo.com.au/serp-preview-tool/